# Find file according to the access time using "grep" and "find" commands

Tags: linux

My goal is to find all text files with extension `.log`, which have the last access more than 24 hours ago and contain the required text.

Here is what I have already tried:

```
find / *.log -mtime +1 -print | grep "next" *.log
```

but this doesn't work.

> Question is: how can I reach the goal I have described above?Maybe some ways to modify my `find` expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your command is that you are running the grep on the output of the find command - which means you are running it on the file names, not content (actually, since you have the *.log at the end, you run it on all *.log files, completely ignoring what  your find command found). also, you need -name in order to filter only the .log files.

you can use the -exec flag of find to execute a command on each of the files that matches your find criteria:

```
find / -name "*.log" -mtime +1 -exec grep 'next' \{};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with [xargs](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs):

```
find / -name "*.log" -mtime +1 | xargs grep "next"
```

But also, note what the [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) manual says about the arg to `-atime` which also applies to `-mtime`. That is, your `mtime` as specified probably doesn't get the time period you want.

> When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last
>   accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a
>   file has to have been accessed at least *two* days ago.

Comment: I'm not sure what `find / *.log` will do- I think like this it will look under / and also under all \*.log files (which basically means all files under /). it needs to be `find / -name "*.log"`

Comment: @NirLevy You're right. I missed the fact that that was missing in the OP's command. Corrected now.